# Android : Type mismatch: cannot convert from EditText to boolean

Tags: android

here is my code
 i try his solution but it didnt work

```
   package com.FF_studio.psp_rd_lite_1;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
        EditText urn,pwd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        }
        public void login(View v) {

            urn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            pwd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            String site = "";
            String error = "用戶名稱或密碼錯誤,請重新輸入";
            String url = "";
            String ans = "admin";
            String ans1 = "rico1010";
            urn.getText().toString();
            pwd.getText().toString();

            if(urn = ans) //error occur here
               url = "";
            else
                Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        }
```

Comment: `urn = ans` tries to assign `ans` to `urn`. One is an `EditText` the other is a `String`. `if(` expects a `boolean` expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems here.

```
urn.getText().toString();
```

doesn't really do anything. You need to assign a variable to it to make use of it.

```
String urnString = urn.getText().toString();
```

Second, `=` is an assignment operator and not a comparison operator. You would want `==` to compare.

Third `==` [is not the right way to compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) you want `.equals()`

Comment: how to use .equals()

Comment: `if(urnString.equals(ans)){ //do something}` [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: thx a lot +codeMagic

Comment: Actually what you are doing is you are assigning ans to urn which is a wrong way However what you need to do is either use '==' operator in your if statement or use if(urn.equals (ans)) { //do your stuff}